# Azure Function doesn't return a 405 response

Tags: azure, azure-functions, http-status-code-405

When a HTTP Trigger is defined for only POST, but the user tries to perform a GET on the same URL, Azure Functions returns a 404 rather than the expected 405.

**What is the best way to return HTTP Status Code 405 in this scenario? (along with the required "Allow" header)**

Of interest, APIM also currently returns 404 instead of 405 responses (https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/32626496).

Comment: For history, seems this is a behavior of the framework, effectively by design. https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/388

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I checked a lot of documents and blogs, but did not find a perfect solution. I have a solution, it looks a little stupid, but it works.

**Solution**

You can allow the use of get requests, and then judge it inside `Function`. If it is a `get` request, manually specify the `405` status code.

[image: code screenshot]

The complete sample code is as follows:

```cs
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static async Task<IActionResult> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", "post", Route = null)] HttpRequest req,
        ILogger log)
    {
        if (req.Method == HttpMethods.Get) {
            var result = new ObjectResult("your message");
            result.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status405MethodNotAllowed;
            return result;
        }
        log.LogInformation("C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.");

        string name = req.Query["name"];

        string requestBody = await new StreamReader(req.Body).ReadToEndAsync();
        dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(requestBody);
        name = name ?? data?.name;

        string responseMessage = string.IsNullOrEmpty(name)
            ? "This HTTP triggered function executed successfully. Pass a name in the query string or in the request body for a personalized response."
            : $"Hello, {name}. This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.";

        return new OkObjectResult(responseMessage);
    }
}
```

The status code returned is expected:

[image: Correct Output in Postman]